# Suppress WebTestException in Visual Studio 2013 webtest when Selected Option context parameter not exist

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-testing

In a Visual Studio 2013 WebTest, I am using the "Selected Option" extraction rule to extract the value of a DropDown into a Context Parameter.  It works fine as long as a selected option exists.  If a selected option does not exist (which in my test is perfectly acceptable) the test throws an exception, "The select tag 'SuchAndSuch' was not found."

The error message is misleading.  When I look at the Response I see that the select tag "SuchAndSuch" does indeed exist, it just does not have a selected option.  That is to say, this Html tag exists:

```
<select name="SuchAndSuch">
```

But it does not have a child tag like this:

```
<option selected="selected">
```

I also tried using "Extract Attribute Value" Extraction Rule to extract the selected item in a dropdown, since this latter rule has a "Required" property.

The rule is to look for the first instance of the tag "option" that has the attribute "selected=selected," and then extract the value of the "value" attribute.  I have "Required" false because this drop-down will not always have a selected item.

The properties of my Extract Attribute Value rule are as follows:

```
<RuleParameters>
        <RuleParameter Name="TagName" Value="option" />
        <RuleParameter Name="AttributeName" Value="value" />
        <RuleParameter Name="MatchAttributeName" Value="selected" />
        <RuleParameter Name="MatchAttributeValue" Value="selected" />
        <RuleParameter Name="HtmlDecode" Value="True" />
        <RuleParameter Name="Required" Value="False" />
        <RuleParameter Name="Index" Value="0" />
</RuleParameters>
```

This works fine as long as the drop-down has a selected item.  When it does not the WebTest throws the WebTestException

> Context Parameter 'SuchAndSuch' not found in test context

and the Request does not execute.

My desired behavior is when this particular drop-down lacks a selected item I want that particular Request to continue to execute and I want the test to NOT log a WebTestException.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in this case is to write a custom extraction rule:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243179(v=vs.120).aspx

The rule I created for my own use is below, it is based on code I stole from here:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/df4f2a0b-2fc4-4d27-9380-ac80100ca0b7/need-help-with-complex-extraction-rule?forum=vstswebtest

I first created the rule in the same project as the webtest.  When I ran the webtest it immediately errored out with a "FileNotFound" exception when it tried to load the extraction rule.  I moved the extraction rule to a separate project and referenced it from the web test project and it solved that problem.

```
[DisplayName("Extract Single-Select Dropdown")]
    [Description("Extracts the attribute value of AttributeName from the selected option if selected option exists.")]
    public class ExtractSingleSelectDropdown : ExtractionRule
    {
        [Description("The 'name' attribute of the rendered 'select' tag.")]
        public string DropdownName { get; set; }
        [Description("The name of the attribute of the rendered 'option' tag that contains the value that is extracted to the Context Parameter.")]
        public string OptionAttributeName { get; set; }
        [Description("When true, sets Success 'false' if a selected option is not found.")]
        public bool Required { get; set; }

        public override void Extract(object sender, ExtractionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Response.HtmlDocument != null)
            {
                var tags = e.Response.HtmlDocument.GetFilteredHtmlTags(new string[] { "select", "option" });
                if (tags != null && tags.Count() > 0)
                {
                    //find the first <select><option selected="selected"> tag
                    var selectedOption = tags.SkipWhile(tag => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tag.GetAttributeValueAsString("name")) || !tag.GetAttributeValueAsString("name").Equals(this.DropdownName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) // skip tags that aren't the select tag we're looking for
                        .Skip(1) // skip the <select> tag
                        .TakeWhile(tag => tag.Name.Equals("option"))
                        .Where(tag => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tag.GetAttributeValueAsString("selected"))) //
                        .FirstOrDefault();

                    if (selectedOption == null)
                    {
                        e.Message = string.Format("Zero selected options in Dropdown {0}", DropdownName);
                        e.WebTest.Context[ContextParameterName] = string.Empty;
                        e.Success = (this.Required ? false : true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.WebTest.Context[ContextParameterName] = selectedOption.GetAttributeValueAsString(OptionAttributeName);
                        e.Success = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```